# trigger 'click' after selected an option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select box which load addresses form via ajax. So user can select previous saved address. Inside address form , another select box which lists 'States'. A shipping is calculated based on 'States' select box change.

I want to trigger a change after loading addresses. I used this code

```
$('select#addressed').change(function() {      
  $('select#states').trigger('change');
});
```

But this will trigger change before new address load.Any way to trigger after loading address?

Comment: you have to put this code in ajax callback function

Comment: show us how you are adding values with ajax

Comment: What happens when you try updating the ajax call? Do you get an error?

Comment: @Yatrix i cant change the ajax function (its drupal and its somewhat complicated). No other way to trigger after load?

Answer (score 2):

Fire the change in the `success` section of the Ajax call. That way it won't fire until the data comes back. You could also use a $.when/.done as well.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: I cant update ajax call (for some reason). I am looking for another solution ie trigger after loading address

Comment: Look into the link I put in the answer about `$.when`. You don't have to change the ajax call, you wrap it in a `when/done` and put the click in the `done`. That way, when the data is finished being received, whatever is in that `done` will be ran. This is especially useful in async transmissions, which it sounds like you're doing.

Comment: not working .. i have updated my code , hope you can understand what i am trying to achieve!

Comment: What you're trying to do is fire the change event for the States select when the address change event is fired, so the shipping is calculated automatically. Correct? But you want to do so AFTER the address information in the form is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by putting the "click" trigger in the complete function. I'm assuming from your syntax and tag you're using jQuery. Have a look at [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) under "complete".

Comment: I cant update ajax call (for some reason). I am looking for another solution ie trigger after loading address